# How do I find the nth occurence of a substring from a specified offset within a text file?

Tags: vb.net, search, full-text-search, indexof

Assume the existence of an unformatted raw text file having variable length lines, delimited by CR/LF-sequences. The FileStream object is named oFS.

I want to extract some portion of it, as a String array, beginning at a position held in the Long named lCandidate. lCandidate is guaranteed to hold a value in the range of 0...oFS.Length-1.

Optionally, the Long lMaxLines can contain a positive number larger than or equal 0. If 0, all lines starting at position lCandidate until the EOF need to be returned, otherwise only the text between lCandidate and the nth occurence of CR/LF-sequences after lCandidate need to be returned.

With lMaxLines = 0, this is not a problem. With lMaxLines > 0, I can write an IndexOf loop and decrement lMaxLines until it reaches 0, at which point I have detected the final position. However, this number might be quite large (for instance a 6 digits number). This search is the function's bottleneck (lCandidate is found binarily).

My question is: is there a more direct way to find the position of the nth occurence of a CR/LF-sequence after a certain offset?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.Encoding

Private Shared Function pExtractLogLines(sLogFile As String,
    sEarliest As String, lMaxLines As Long, lKeyStart As Long) As String()

    Dim oFS As New FileStream(sLogFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
        FileShare.Read)             'The log file as file stream.
    Dim abKey() As Byte             'Reading the current key.
    Dim lCandidate As Long          'File position of promising candidate.
    Dim sRecords As String          'All wanted records.

    ...

    'lCandidate points to a position before the first record we are 
    'interested in, which commences after the next CR/LF sequence.
    'Note, that we need the final CR/LF here, so that the search for the next
    'CR/LF sequence following below will match a valid first entry even in 
    'case there are no entries to be returned (sEarliest being larger than 
    'the last log line). 
    oFS.Seek(lCandidate, SeekOrigin.Begin)      'Position the stream.
    If lMaxLines = 0 Then
        'There is no limit in the number of records to be returned. Return 
        'all records until EOF.
        ReDim abKey(CInt(oFS.Length - lCandidate - 1))      '0-based.
        oFS.Read(abKey, 0, CInt(oFS.Length - lCandidate))
    Else
        'Only a maximum of lMaxLines variable length records need to be 
        'returned.
```

Is there a faster way accessing possibly thousands of variable length records delimited by CR/LF-sequences, than using a loop to execute thousands of IndexOf statements?

```
    End If

    'We're done with the stream.
    oFS.Close()

    'Convert into a string, but omit the first (partial) line, then return
    'as a string array split at CR/LF, without the empty last entry.
    sRecords = UTF8.GetString(abKey)
    sRecords = sRecords.Substring(sRecords.IndexOf(Chr(10)) + 1)

    Return sRecords.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray(),
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
End Function
```

Comment: You might try using a `StreamReader` and call its `ReadLine` method `n` times?  Alternately you could read the file in chunks and count the `CR/LF` pairs.  That may be faster.

Comment: In addition to what @ChrisDunaway said about reading it in chunks: You could read it in chunks _in parallel_. Say you split this into for example four parallel tasks; each checking a chunk of 1/4th of the file?